# Angular ngOnChanges on service

Tags: angular

So, I have a class as below:

**item.model.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class itemView {
   id: any; 
}
```

Then, in one component file there is a function that changes the ID:

**Component_A.ts**

```
 constructor(public itemID: itemView) {};

 getItemID(number){ //"<div (swipe)="getItemID(number)"></div>   
    this.itemID.id = this.selection[number];// ex: value change to "2"
 }
```

Then In another component, I want to detect the `id` value change and do something with it: This is what I have so far:

**Component_B.ts:**

```
import { SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes[this.itemID.id]) {
       console.log("It changed");
    }
}
```

But I am not getting any results. Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should make `itemView` responsible of the change and notify to the components that something happend there.

Comment: ngOnChanges is a lifecycle hook that fires when an @Input property changes. So if you are not passing the id from component a to component b through an input directive, then that hook won't fire. Camaron is right, you'll need an rxjs subject to transmit changes to components that are listening. Here is a good article on that type of component communication (http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)

Comment: Thanks guys. I will read the article. Much appreciated.